# VPN SSTP support in ubuntu network manager ... [ubuntu 15.04, 64bits]

Tags: networking, vpn, 15.04, pptp

I've downloaded these DEB packages from http://sourceforge.net/projects/sstp-client/

1. libsstp-client0_1.0.9_amd64.deb
2. sstp-client_1.0.9_amd64.deb
3. network-manager-sstp_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
4. network-manager-sstp-gnome_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

first and second are installed successfully, but 3. step is critical for me. Because network-manager-sstp_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb needs package ppp version 3.4.6 or lower and in my system is version 2.4.6-3.1ubuntu1 ... please help

Comment: 3. step => dpkg error => "network-manager-sstp depends on ppa (<< 2.4.6); but ppp version 2.4.6-3.1ubuntu1 is installed"

Comment: I've tried to force installation "network-manager-sstp_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb" using dpkg --ignore-depends=ppp parameter. Installation sucessed but SSTP VPN connection is not available in network-manager

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else still has this problem, just use the PPA sources mentioned on the page above. I.e.,

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 61FF9694161CE595
Put the following two lines into the following file:
 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sstp-client.list
  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/eivnaes/network-manager-sstp/ubuntu vivid main 
  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/eivnaes/network-manager-sstp/ubuntu vivid main 

Then use your apt-get command to get both network-manager-sstp and sstp-client.
```

This will install network-manager-sstp 0.9.10.0, for which the ppp version is not a problem. This fixed it for me.

Comment: For the latest version, refer to the enaess Github repo where those instructions are updated for the latest Ubuntu version. https://github.com/enaess/network-manager-sstp